# Hide action in ruby based on criteria?

Tags: ruby, action, edit, destroy

Say I want only view to be visible to most people and having

`actions :all, :except => [:edit, :new, :destroy]`

accomplishes this.  I need to have users designated as `prime_user` to get access to edit.

So how would I do this?

I can't just do actions `:edit` can I?

I get an error for this.

Answer (score 1):

Use [before_filter](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#filters).  The example given seems to be just what you are asking for.